# Diffrent result between gst-launch-1.0.exe with gst_parse_launch()

Tags: gstreamer

I have a  pipline like below，I push the image data into the appsrc.When I played an image of this pipeline with gst-launch-1.0.exe, the image was fine, but when I loaded the same pipeline with gst_parse_launch, the image got a severe flower screen and the entire image was green. I don't know if GST-launch-1.0.exe has a special processing of the pipeline, or how should I determine the difference between using gst-launch-1.0 and gst_parse_launch?
(1)video src pipline:

```
GError *error = NULL;
gchar *video_caps = g_strdup_printf("video/x-raw,format=\"BGRA\",width=%d,height=%d,framerate=%d/1", width, height, target_fps);
gchar *pipeline = g_strdup_printf("appsrc is-live=0 block=1 caps=\"%s\" name=\"appsrc\"  ! queue !  videoconvert ! nvh265enc bitrate=81920 preset=2 zerolatency=1 ! h265parse ! rtph265pay config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.2 port=5902", video_caps); 
priv->pipeline = gst_parse_launch(pipeline, &error);
```

(2)dst pipline load by gst-launch-1.0.exe，I can get normal video

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=5902 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H265 ! rtph265depay ! queue ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! d3d11videosink
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPlLq.jpg)

(3)dst pipline load by gst_parse_launch() function,the image got a severe flower screen and the entire image was green.

```
pipeline = g_strdup_printf("udpsrc port=5902 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H265 ! rtph265depay ! queue ! h265parse !  nvh265dec ! videoconvert !  d3d11videosink name=\"displaysink\"");
p->stream1.pipe = gst_parse_launch(pipeline, &error);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxmuk.jpg)

I used the exact same channel descriptor on the video side and loaded it with gst-launch-1.0 and gst_parse_launch respectively, but got different results, I wonder what's the difference between them

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the program in release mode solves this problem. It is not clear why the above problem occurs in debug mode.